# Why TClientSocket.OnRead event fires two times for a single server send

Tags: windows, delphi, sockets, tcp

So, I have a TClientSocket which have to receive over 10KB of data in one OnRead event. But when the event is triggered it only gets 8KB of data, then the event fires again with the rest of the data.

Why is this happens?

Comment: That is the reason why there are blocking clients which handle this for you, like Indy or Synapse - if the client expects 10kb, it can read 10 in a single call. The library will put the pieces together. (But this can block, so it works best in a thread).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because TCP is a stream protocol, not message-based. You must receive whatever you have been sent, merge it to one stream of data, then parse the stream according to used protocol.

Comment: Exactly. When you're using TCP you only get a stream of bytes. A single Send may be split into multiple packets, and several Sends may be merged into a single packet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a server-client agreed protocol that will signal the end of the message nad by that to parse the streaming to complete messages.

Comment: Signal the end of the message. How that i forgot this? Thanks.